# Windows phone screensaver? Possible?

Tags: windows-phone, screensaver

I want to make a screensaver in a windows phone application. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you finding that the battery on your phone doesn't drain fast enough under normal usage?

Comment: The battery doesn't matter.. it's only for testing.. I only want to know how can i make a screensaver..

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

For now, you can't.

Currently there is no way to schedule the start an application.

Answer (score 0):

What you can is create an app that does some sort of animation (like a screensaver does) and just manually run it... I know, i't not a screensaver per say (it won't automatically run if you just leave the device idle) but it's the best you will manage to achieve right now in Windows Phone...

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you are in Windows phone development team. Windows phone development team will have access to internal dlls through which you can create screensaver. But as a individual developer, we can't do it!